# Bookmarklet: add an URL before head URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

this is probably extremely simple but I am a total newbie. I want to add something in the beginning of an URL, like this:

orignial URL:
https://www.example.com/new-article

and with the bookmarklet I want to make the URL looks like this

https://testtool.com/testing-tool#url=https://www.example.com/new-article

I tried something like this

```
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/www\./,'https://testtool.com/testing-tool#url=https';})()
```

but it isn't working.

Can you help me?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Why are you doing a replace? Why are you not just appending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would be replacing when you are just taking the current URL and sticking it on as a hash

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com#url=' + window.location.href
```

or

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com#url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
```